# How can I implement cloning elements onto canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm struggling with making clones of draggable elements onto the canvas (droppable element). So far I could only drag one original image but I need a copy of it instead to be able to drag to. And here's how it has to work [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BifV.png) and how it works right now [source 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6HJp.png) [source 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7CPH.png).
So it didn't work with other images.

```js
// 1 - wall, 0 - free/street
const map1 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0]
];

const city = map1;
const size = 41;

window.onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //draw images
  const p = ctx.lineWidth; //padding
  for (let i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < city[i].length; j++) {
      const x = i * size;
      const y = j * size;
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, size + p * 2, size + p * 2);
      };
      img.src = city[i][j] == 0 ? "images/white.png" : "images/black.png";
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  let currentDroppable = null;
  const cam1 = document.getElementById('cam1');

  cam1.onmousedown = function(event) {

    let shiftX = event.clientX - cam1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - cam1.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    cam1.style.position = 'absolute';
    cam1.style.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.append(cam1);

    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
      cam1.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
      cam1.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

      cam1.hidden = true;
      let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      cam1.hidden = false;

      if (!elemBelow) return;

      let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('#canvas');
      if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
        if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
          leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
        }
        currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
        if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
          // (maybe just left the droppable)
          enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
        }
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    cam1.onmouseup = function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      cam1.onmouseup = null;
    };

  };


  function enterDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = 'blue';
  }

  function leaveDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = '';
  }

  cam1.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

h1,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#game {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}

#cam1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cameras {
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>cameras of the city</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>cameras of the city</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="game">
    <canvas height="450px" width="450px" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="cameras">
      <img id="cam1" src="images/camera1.png">
      <img id="cam2" src="images/camera2.png">
      <img id="cam3" src="images/camera3.png">
      <img id="cam4" src="images/camera4.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    created:
  </footer>

  <script src="js/core.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you have to:

- clone `cam1` on mousedown.
- Add the top and left `cam1` properties to the cloned object.
- Append to body then move the cloned object and add corresponding events to it.

I will use jQuery since it's included in snippet above.

**Edit:**

Code below for drag all images not only `cam1`:

```js
// 1 - wall, 0 - free/street
        const map1 = [
          [1, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 0, 0]
        ];

        const city = map1;
        const size = 41;

        window.onload = function() {
          const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

          //draw images
          const p = ctx.lineWidth; //padding
          for (let i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < city[i].length; j++) {
              const x = i * size;
              const y = j * size;
              const img = new Image();
              img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, size + p * 2, size + p * 2);
              };
              img.src = city[i][j] == 0 ? "images/white.png" : "images/black.png";
            }
          }
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
          let currentDroppable = null, clone;

          function moveAt(pageX, pageY, shiftX, shiftY) {
              clone.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
              clone.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
            }

            function onMouseMove(event) {
              moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY, 0, 0);

              clone.hidden = true;
              let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
              clone.hidden = false;

              if (!elemBelow) return;

              let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('#canvas');
              if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
                if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
                  leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
                }
                currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
                if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
                  // (maybe just left the droppable)
                  enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
                }
              }
            }

          $(document).on('mousedown', '.drag', function(e){

            var tmp = $(this).clone().removeClass("drag");
            $(tmp).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(this).offset().top + "px", left: $(this).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});
            $('body').append($(tmp));

            clone = $(tmp)[0];

            let shiftX = event.clientX - clone.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            let shiftY = event.clientY - clone.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY, shiftX, shiftY);

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

            clone.onmouseup = function() {
              document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
              clone.onmouseup = null;
            };

          });


          function enterDroppable(elem) {
            elem.style.background = 'blue';
          }

          function leaveDroppable(elem) {
            elem.style.background = '';
          }

          cam1.ondragstart = function() {
            return false;
          };
        });
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

h1,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#game {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}

.drag {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cameras {
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>cameras of the city</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>cameras of the city</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="game">
    <canvas height="450px" width="450px" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="cameras">
      <img id="cam1" class="drag" src="images/camera1.png">
      <img id="cam2" class="drag" src="images/camera2.png">
      <img id="cam3" class="drag" src="images/camera3.png">
      <img id="cam4" class="drag" src="images/camera4.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    created:
  </footer>

  <script src="js/core.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works with some delay once you pick first camera but okay. Can it be done for the other 3 too because I tried to implement the same logic for other cameras but it didn't work?

Comment: I intended to not add a full code since it needs to be more organized and refactored. please find the updated answer. btw, I didn't find delay in code above. maybe after adding images src could be noticed based on images.

Comment: It does work right now with all cameras, huge thx, however, once you picked up and placed it on the canvas and want to move it again so it duplicates again and already placed cameras only can be placed once, is it intended to be like that?

Comment: Okay, so just remove class drag from the cloned object, I've just updated the answer.

Comment: And could you please look at making those roads on canvas to be blue once the camera is placed according to the number in the image of cameras? There's an ideal working example in the description, I'll attach a link to the images, thank you.

Comment: It's another issue. please close this question if the answer accepted and open a new one to draw the road on canvas.